# Using decimal numbers in EXP4J

Tags: java, android, parsing

Since EXP4J requires a zero before a decimal, is there a way to have java automatically add the zero if the number does not have a zero before the decimal instead of giving an invalid error?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: exp4j 0.4.0 does support this, but it's still in an alpha state.